# String table name not working in a query with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I would like to generate dynamic queries with variables for column names and table name. This is my code:

```
query = sql.SQL("select {fields} from {table}").format(fields=sql.SQL(',').join([
    sql.Identifier(country_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(time_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(value_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(type_column_id),
]),
table=sql.Identifier(table_name))

cursor.execute(query)
```

I get the following error:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "d1dbforest.interface.v_monitoring_ind34a4" does not exist
> LINE 1: select "country","year","data","use" from "d1dbforest.interf...

I noticed that in pgAdmin4 I can run

```
select "country","year","data","use" from d1dbforest.interface.v_monitoring_ind34a4
```

but not

```
select "country","year","data","use" from "d1dbforest.interface.v_monitoring_ind34a4"
```

So, it looks like I cannot use a string table name in the query. Maybe it is also worth to note that I am connecting to a view, not a table. Can anyone suggest a way to inject a table name as a variable to a query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you quote  something,it is considered as one object while "d1dbforest.interface.v_monitoring_ind34a4" is referring to 3 objects , database name , schema name and view name :

so you need to quote them separately: `"d1dbforest"."interface"."v_monitoring_ind34a4"`

so:

```
select "country","year","data","use" from "d1dbforest"."interface"."v_monitoring_ind34a4"
```

then you have to specify it in the identifier :

```
query = sql.SQL("select {fields} from {table}").format(fields=sql.SQL(',').join([
    sql.Identifier(country_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(time_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(value_column_id),
    sql.Identifier(type_column_id),
]),
table=sql.Identifier(db_name,schema_name,table_name))
```

reference: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

Comment: The query now indeed works. Going perhaps a bit beyond the scope of the initial question, now the query returns None. 
print(query.as_string(connection)) returns select "country","year","data","use" from "d1dbforest"."interface"."v_monitoring_ind34a4", which in pgAdmin4 returns the table. So, I think there is still something wrong with the query string.
The following lines are simply:     
result = cursor.execute(query)
print(result)

Comment: @Eylül that can be permission issue or connecting to wrong server

Comment: My following code was wrong. It should have been:
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())
Thank you so much!